# How to execute an exe using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have create an Windows Application in .net. I need to execute the exe generated by the application using powershell.

Comment: Invoke-Expression "& `"F:\Installation Validator\My...Tools\InstallationValidator\bin\Debug\Validator.exe`"

Comment: I need to execute the exe by using powershell script

Answer (score 2):

I would usually use the call operator (&):

```
$args = @('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
& app.exe $args
```

A complete list of your available options are detailed [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx).

Comment: what are the arguments we needed to pass?How can I specify the path?

Comment: You don't have to pass any arguments, they would depend on your EXE; I was just demonstrating usage. Simply provide the full path to the operator e.g. & 'c:\windows\notepad.exe'

Comment: I try to running the script like this 
& 'F:\Installation Validator\My...Tools\InstallationValidator\bin\Debug\Validator.exe' But it shows alert 'XML File not configured properly'

Comment: I Running the powershell script in the PowerGUI Script Editor tool